# How do I tell if a character is an 'e' in C#?

Tags: c#, unicode

What I'm looking for is not just a 'e' or 'E', but also any e with accident characters.

Comment: Have a list of all unicode characters you consider "an 'e'" and check if that list contains the character you want.

Comment: "accident characters": That's a cute accident.

Answer (score 5):

The probably best way to go is:

1. Move it to NFKD (Normalization Form Compatibility Decomposition)
2. Filter all the combining characters out.
3. Test whether you have just `e` or `E` left.

MSDN reference for [`string.Normalize(System.Text.NormalizationForm.FormKD)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebza6ck1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: exactly the way to do it ... for a more complete answer a reference to String.Normalize() would have been nice ;)

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42: Well, yes. Added that.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to make a list of all the possible Es. Thankfully, they all have more or less the same title: 'Latin Capital Letter E', 'Latin Capital Letter E with Acute', 'Latin Small Letter E', etc...

So, use your favorite search engine to look for `Unicode 'Latin Capital Letter E'` and `Unicode 'Latin Small Letter E'` and go over the search results to compile your list.